# mysql won't import database dump file on Windows XP

Tags: mysql

I created a data base using mysql.  I used MySQLDump to create one database backup file in text format (MySql 5.5 on Windows XP).  The database is local on my machine (local host).

I am having trouble using the MySQL command to load the dump file to restore the database.  I have done the following:

1. Research stack overflow for how to do it.  I noticed there's a bug using the MySQL command to restore the data from a post.  Before I run the command, I DROP the database and CREATE the database using MySQL workbench.
2. I type the following command in the DOS prompt to restore the database:
   mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D matlab_data -o < backup.sql
3. backup.sql is a the backup file in text format created by MySqlDump.
4. I am then asked for the password which I enter.  I get the DOS prompt right away with no error message.  I've waited several hours for the command to run and the database is still empty.

I have tried various command formats over the last few days.  If I enter incorrect data in the command line (non existen file, database, etc), I get an error message.

I feel I would not see the DOS prompt until the database is restored.  If I don't DROP and CREATE the database, I get an error message.  Otherwise, not.

Does anybody have any idea what the issue is?  I realize that I could be making a stupid mistake.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you check if the dump file actually contains anything?

Comment: Please show us in the question the exact paramaters you used to perform the mysqldump that produced backkup.sql

Comment: Thank you for your help.  To answer your questions: The dump file does contain data and is around 6 MB.  I put the MySQLDump command in a batch file that is run every morning.  The extact command is:   "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump" -u root -ptest123 --result-file="c:\db_backup\backup.%DATE:~0,3%.sql" matlab_data

Answer (score 1):

shell into the mysql console and run the sql file as this

If you are already running mysql, you can execute an SQL script file using the source command or . command:

```
mysql> source file_name
mysql> \. file_name
```

note that `file_name`  must be an absolut path